# Redirect all network traffic except ssh

Tags: ssh, iptables, nat

I have a Linux box (let's call it **Network Probe**) that i would like to use for network monitoring. I need to redirect ALL the traffic for ALL the protocols coming to ETH0 to another machine (**Network Mon**) on the same subnet. Also i need to connect on the probe in SSH.

It's possible to redirect all the network traffic except the SSH?

I tried with the following iptables rules; the NAT component works well but i cannot access SSH any more.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p all -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert an **ACCEPT** before **DNAT**

```bash
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

`-I` inserts it to the begining of the chain

Comment: Thank you gabor.zed. It works well!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Complete answer is :

```bash
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p all -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p all -d x.x.x.x -j MASQURADE
```